# How send info from class method when dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) is runing

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a ViewController, and after tap button i want get data from web.

```
let myClass = Class()
    myClass.myMethod() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {               
        }
    }
```

In my Class file i have a method

```
func myMethod( completion:()->() ) {  
    if let connectToInternetAndGetDataFromWeb
        completion()
    } else {
        print("Cold not construct a valid URL")
        completion()
    }
}
```

And my class to connect to internet and getting data is

```
func downloadJSONFromURL() {
    if let httpResponse {
        switch(httpResponse.statusCode) {
        case 200:
        // 2. Create JSON Object with data
            do { 
                try 
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }             
    } else {
        print("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")            
    }   
    dataTask!.resume()
}
```

And my question is how sent feedback to ViewController to show alert information from class. If i have internet connection is ok but for example when i give wrong web address i have error **print("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")** but how can i send this error to ViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. 
I think the easiest part for your case is adding a closure parameter in the `downloadJSONFromURL()`.

```
func downloadJSONFromURL(completion:((error:NSError?)->Void)) {
    if let httpResponse {
        switch(httpResponse.statusCode) {
        case 200:
        // 2. Create JSON Object with data
            do { 
                try 
                completion(nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                completion(error)
            }
        }             
    } else {
        print("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")            
    }   
    dataTask!.resume()
}
```

Of course you have to chain the completion closure up to your `UIViewController` that is making the request. So the `myMethod`also gets an optional error parameter in it's closure and so on.
In the end you have your UIViewController class like this

```
let myClass = Class()
    myClass.myMethod() {(error:NSError?) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
          //Show Alert or whatever is necessary for the error
        }
    }
```